# How to correctly configure Qt app to launch on wayland platform?

Tags: qt5, qtwayland

Currently trying to launch a Qt application on a wayland platform, without success. I succeeded to launch other basic apps such as a calculator or a paint sample. But my app get the following error :

> QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

I can't find the cause of this error. Tried to launch the app with the env variable "qt.qpa.plugin" using the following values : 
 wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl
getting always the same error.

What kind of behavior triggers this error ?

Comment: Are you using QSocketNotifier? If so can you post relevant code?

Comment: I did not found a QSocketNotifier in the project. Maybe it is a part of other objects used by qt, I will look in this way

Comment: [This](https://forum.qt.io/topic/29587/solved-qsocketnotifier-can-only-be-used-with-threads-started-with-qthread) might be relevant?

Comment: Yep, It could be a Thread-Safety related issue as stated in the article. Thanks for finding this topic, I missed this one.

Comment: FYI: The name of the env var is `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` (uppercase and underscores), but I don't think it shoud matter in this case... You should try to create a minimal failing example and post it on https://bugreports.qt.io